# Google should only index the redirect. How?

Tags: seo

Let say I have a webpage: www.test.com/action
On that url there is a page with a automatic redirect in the HTML, so it will redirected to another page: action.blabla.com.

I want google to only index the redirect page, and prevent to index the page where is redirected to.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: You should redirect on the HTTP level, then Google will index only the destination.

Comment: @inflagranti it appears he wants the opposite: Google indexes the first page, but browsers continue on to the second. This will be difficult to achieve, because Google is designed to index what browsers see.

Comment: Ah yeah, should have read more carefully. Don't really see *why* anyone would like to want such thing though!?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Answer (score 2):

Canonical link:

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139394?hl=en

Quoted:
Add a rel="canonical" link to the  section of the non-canonical version of each HTML page.
To specify a canonical link to the page http://www.example.com/product.php?item=swedish-fish, create a  element as follows:

Copy this link into the  section of all non-canonical versions of the page, such as http://www.example.com/product.php?item=swedish-fish&sort=price.

If you publish content on both http://www.example.com/product.php?item=swedish-fish and https://www.example.com/product.php?item=swedish-fish, you can specify the canonical version of the page. Create the  element:

Add this link to the  section of https://www.example.com/product.php?item=swedish-fish.

Indicate the canonical version of a URL by responding with the Link rel="canonical" HTTP header. Adding rel="canonical" to the head section of a page is useful for HTML content, but it can't be used for PDFs and other file types indexed by Google Web Search. In these cases you can indicate a canonical URL by responding with the Link rel="canonical" HTTP header, like this (note that to use this option, you'll need to be able to configure your server):